# onLoadFinished called with wrong data even if loadInBackground returns correct data

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, asynctaskloader

I am making an app to display the movies list as shown in the screenshot.

*The problem is that when I select the options menu top_rated option it reloads the correct data but the list returned to onLoadFinished contains the previous data with the new data after that*.

How do I rectify this as **I want only the new data to be in the list**. I tried **onLoaderReset** but it is not called because the activity is not destroyed and I am not able to find any other way to dereference the old data or in other words **first empty the old already fetched list and then replace it with a newly fetched list**.

How to achieve the above..?

And there is one more thing, that whenever I go to any other activity and then return back the data shown is duplicated. I know that this might be a lifecycle issue and can be solved with some research but I can do that only if the first issue is resolved.

Here is the screenshot of the app:-
[image: Screenshot of MainActivity]
**UPDATE --> The actual problem was not in MainActivity.java but in the below file and hence the problem is solved now as mentioned in my answer.**

Here is my JSONUtils.java function which I was calling in MainActivity.java:-

```
import com.example.trishantsharma.popularmovies.Movie;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JSONUtils {
private static ArrayList<String[]> movieTitleAndPosterList = new ArrayList<>();
//ALL CONSTANTS HERE
public static ArrayList<String[]> parseMovieJSON(String jsonReceived){
    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE AND HAS BEEN RECTIFIED IN THE ANSWER
    try {
        JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject(jsonReceived);
        JSONArray allMoviesArray = movieObject.getJSONArray(RESULT_JSON_ARRAY_STRING);
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            JSONObject particularMovie = allMoviesArray.optJSONObject(i);
            String movieId = Integer.toString(particularMovie.optInt(ID_JSON_OBJECT_STRING));
            String moviePoster = particularMovie.optString(POSTER_JSON_OBJECT_STRING);
            String[] singleMovieTitleAndPosterArray = {movieId,moviePoster};
            movieTitleAndPosterList.add(singleMovieTitleAndPosterArray);
        }
        return movieTitleAndPosterList;
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In onFinished you clears movieTitleAndPosterPathFinalList and addAll same list. Means you first empty list and then adds within it.

Comment: Yes. I have done that but even after that it doesn’t help. Actually the movieTitleAndPosterPathList is returned after like the one I have explained.

Comment: Show your onLoadFinished which is in parent class.

Comment: Parent class ?? This is the main class. What class should I show ?

Comment: LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

Comment: But that is a predefined class in the Android Support Library. I haven’t made any other class regarding Loader Callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I referenced to in my question:-

Here is my JSONUtils.java function which I was calling in MainActivity.java:-

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> parseMovieJSON(String jsonReceived){
    movieTitleAndPosterList.clear();
    try {
        JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject(jsonReceived);
        JSONArray allMoviesArray = movieObject.getJSONArray(RESULT_JSON_ARRAY_STRING);
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            JSONObject particularMovie = allMoviesArray.optJSONObject(i);
            String movieId = Integer.toString(particularMovie.optInt(ID_JSON_OBJECT_STRING));
            String moviePoster = particularMovie.optString(POSTER_JSON_OBJECT_STRING);
            String[] singleMovieTitleAndPosterArray = {movieId,moviePoster};
            movieTitleAndPosterList.add(singleMovieTitleAndPosterArray);
        }
        return movieTitleAndPosterList;
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Since the ArrayList here was **static** therefore I had to **clear** it before adding new data.

*Since, I was not clearing it the data was always getting appended to the list and hence the list returned to onLoadFinished had duplicated items.*

Thanks @KavinRajuS for taking the time in helping me solve this query.
Hence, the problem is now fixed and the app is working well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by clearing the data in the **RecyclerView Adapter**, when you click an option in the menu, and then reload the data.

*This goes inside your* **RecyclerView Adapter Class.**

```
 public void cleatMovieData(){
    int size = movieDetails.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            movieDetails.remove(0);
        }
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,size);
    }
}
```

You can call this method before you call the Loader to Restart.

Comment: Okay but, just now I noticed another thing after I added this line of code in my loadInBackground() and adding a local arraylist to the loader. The code is: `if(!receivedArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                receivedArrayList.clear();
            }
receivedArrayList = JSONUtils.parseMovieJSON(jsonReceived);
            return receivedArrayList;`
After this, the thing I noticed is that when I click on top rated the RecyclerView does get updated but the new movies are after the old movies being shown and when I click on a movie and then come back only the new movies are shown.

Comment: I can confirm this as I used a Log statement to check that the ''if'' statement is being returned or not. 
Although, I am now trying your method to check.

Comment: Yeah, @TrishantSharma I also encountered the same situation, but after that, I solved it by first clearing the data in the adapter using the code which I shared now and then reset the conditions for Pagination then called the Loader to do Network call.

Comment: And one more thing regarding your answer that the method you provided goes inside the Adapter class but the list that is returned to onLoadFinished is the wrong one and the wrong list is then supplied to the Adapter. Adding something to the Adapter would not be of much help.

Comment: I couldn't get you. How does it be the wrong one? Do you mean that it is not querying for the currently selected option?

Comment: I am not using Pagination. And after using the method you provided the app crashes showing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException message.

Comment: That is the main problem @KavinRajuS . The query is done correctly and the JSON recieved is also correct and moreover the parsed JSON List is also correct but when I return that same very list then the old list data after which the new list data is returned. But, after I added the code I earlier commented, after clicking on a movie and coming back, onLoadFinished() is again called with the correct data. I am literally very confused regarding that.

Comment: Try using these methods when you add data.
    notifyItemInserted(POSITON_WHERE_DATA_WAS_INSERTED); 
    notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: What methods...?

Comment: I am getting in a very weird situation now. In the method provided by you here, if I log out the size of the received list it is showing 19 and then it showing IndexOutOfBoundsException with Index: 10 Size: 9. Really....? What is happening here ?

Comment: I got the same error while using this code 
movieDetails.remove(i);

Comment: I used the your way but nothing helped !!
I hope that I solve it soon !! ☹️

Comment: Yeah sure @TrishantSharma But I am pretty sure that this is one of the ways of clearing the data in an Adapter.
I would suggest you go through my code and find for any solution if any.